# XML data type optimizing with selective indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i am struggling to improve performance of a query using xml column type in sql server 2012. I have a table called 'xmltable' with as columns, id (int) and a xml column 'xmlvalue'.

The id contains just ids and this is an example of an xmlvalue value:

```
<records><record><id>1</id><name>Melly</name></record><record><id>2</id><name>Ulrike</name></record><record><id>3</id><name>Susanne</name></record><record><id>4</id><name>Tarrance</name></record><record><id>5</id><name>Kasper</name></record><record><id>6</id><name>Linnet</name></record><record><id>7</id><name>Genia</name></record><record><id>8</id><name>Rianon</name></record><record><id>9</id><name>Marcelia</name></record><record><id>10</id><name>Vinny</name></record><record><id>11</id><name>Erin</name></record><record><id>12</id><name>Arielle</name></record><record><id>13</id><name>Adriane</name></record><record><id>14</id><name>Dixie</name></record><record><id>15</id><name>Terrye</name></record><record><id>16</id><name>Tish</name></record><record><id>17</id><name>Ginnie</name></record><record><id>18</id><name>Nat</name></record><record><id>19</id><name>Courtney</name></record><record><id>20</id><name>Dallas</name></record><record><id>21</id><name>Elly</name></record><record><id>22</id><name>Hershel</name></record><record><id>23</id><name>Gardner</name></record><record><id>24</id><name>Christoph</name></record><record><id>25</id><name>Richie</name></record><record><id>26</id><name>Reggi</name></record><record><id>27</id><name>Heywood</name></record><record><id>28</id><name>Hercules</name></record><record><id>29</id><name>Gawain</name></record><record><id>30</id><name>Adolphe</name></record><record><id>31</id><name>Lawton</name></record><record><id>32</id><name>Brooke</name></record><record><id>33</id><name>Rachelle</name></record><record><id>34</id><name>Dani</name></record><record><id>35</id><name>Sebastian</name></record><record><id>36</id><name>Guenevere</name></record><record><id>37</id><name>Perrine</name></record><record><id>38</id><name>Spenser</name></record><record><id>39</id><name>Kath</name></record><record><id>40</id><name>Kyrstin</name></record><record><id>41</id><name>Claudelle</name></record><record><id>42</id><name>Nicolas</name></record><record><id>43</id><name>Gherardo</name></record><record><id>44</id><name>Trefor</name></record><record><id>45</id><name>Bonny</name></record><record><id>46</id><name>Keri</name></record><record><id>47</id><name>Margie</name></record><record><id>48</id><name>Merle</name></record><record><id>49</id><name>Archambault</name></record><record><id>50</id><name>Paulie</name></record></records>
```

The table will have multiple records. The idea is to get all rows' xmlvalue and sort the data on the name node of my xml. I am using this query for this:

```
select
    id, 
    x.e.value('(id/text())[1]','int') as xmlid,
    x.e.value('(name/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as xmlname
from dbo.xmltable tt
cross apply tt.xmlvalue.nodes('/records/record') as x(e)
ORDER BY xmlname ASC
```

This works but goes rather slowly (taking almost **2 minutes** for 100000 rows with each xmlvalue of 50 record-nodes).

So then I looked into xml indexes and selective xml indexes. I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to improve the performance...

- Tried adding a primary xml index -> everything went even slower
- Then added the secondary xml indexes (all three types) -> no improvement

Last thing i tried was add a selective index, mapping to the selectors that i use in my query like this:

```
CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX SXI_Selective_RecordDetails
ON dbo.xmltable(xmlvalue)
FOR 
(
    pathRecord = '/records/record' AS XQUERY 'node()',
    pathNameValueRecord = '/records/record/name/text()' AS XQUERY 'xs:string' SINGLETON,
    pathIdValueRecord = '/records/record/id/text()' AS XQUERY 'xs:double' SINGLETON

)
GO
```

But still no luck in improving performance.

Is there anyone able to give me a hand? That would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might read [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663), do understand, in which cases an *XML index* might help and in which cases this index will make things even worse...

Personally I'd avoid XML indexes...

Do you have a good reason to store this data as XML? XML is not meant for such a purpose...

I'd rather shuffle this data in a `1:n`-related indexed table and re-create the XML whenever you need this...

Comment: Hey Shnugo, big thanks for you answer, I already lurked in that other post ;-) The reason we store the data like this is because it will be a dynamic table of results. An administrator van create some sort of form definition (also stored as xml). Based on that definition the enduser will be able to fill in a form and his results will be stored in the xml field as posted in the original question. So we use this for dynamic nodes of responses. First we thought of creating result tables on the fly but xml columns seemed more flexible, as we saw it. Would be nice to have a second opinion on this.

Comment: @Verthosa Dynamic data is not easy to query, indexes won't help you that much... You might use an *indexed view*, one for each family of data, or - if you need sorting after the same field in all cases - I'd store the XML in this sort order (read about `FLWOR XQuery`).